# nothing provides lighttpd-module-compress needed by lighttpd-1.4.69-r0.aarch64 [ YOCTO DUNFELL VERSION ]

Tags: yocto, devtools, bitbake

I have tried to update lighttpd package in yocto(dunfell) version.
current lighttpd version is 1.4.55 and i am upgrade it into 1.4.69 and compile the image while i am getting this error called **"nothing provides lighttpd-module-compress needed by lighttpd-1.4.69-r0.aarch64"**

I tried to compile with devtool and bitbake but same error i am getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

lighttpd mod_compress was replaced by lighttpd mod_deflate starting with lighttpd 1.4.56, released in Nov 2020 (almost 3 years ago!)

Uninstall lighttpd-module-compress and install lighttpd-module-deflate?

Comment: how can I do that for Lighttpd 1.4.69 I am getting an error while compiling this package.

Comment: Your comment is grossly lacking in details ("I am getting an error").  lighttpd official documentation: https://wiki.lighttpd.net/InstallFromSource  For how to build a package on Yocto, see Yocto documentation.

Answer (score 2):

This might be happening due to your Yocto version being different.